# Why am I getting the error 'await' outside async function in this code

Tags: python

I have this error message `'await' outside async function` I am completely confused on what I am doing wrong. here is my code:

```py
    def check(reaction, user):
      member = message.mentions[0]
      role = get(message.guild.roles, name= 'Vikings')
      fa = get(message.guild.roles, name= 'Free Agents')
      return user == member and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅' and reaction.message == message
      try:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=600, check=check)
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await member.remove_roles(fa)
        await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} Has Accepted **Minnesota Vikings** offer in the time given')
      except asyncio.TimeoutError:
          await message.channel.send(f'{member.mention} did not come to a decision in time.')
      else:
```

Comment: You just can't use the `await` keyword inside a function that is not declared a coroutine with `async def`.

Comment: Yeah, isn't `member` a simple data structure of some kind?  If so, putting `await` in front of access to that makes no sense.  Not knowing the libraries involved very well, I'm guessing that the other three instances might be correct.

Comment: @Steve the library looks like discord.py, and yes it's all correct usage of await.

Comment: Well, it can't ALL be right, can it?  If it were, the OP wouldn't be getting that error, right? - I do admit that i had very little idea what I was talking about.  That's why I didn't give a single thought to making my comment an answer :)

Comment: The error is pretty clear: you can't use `await` outside an async function. In this case, `check()` is not declared `async`. A quick google search for the error finds several hits to solve the problem.

Comment: Ok @SethPeace, I now see what you mean.  His error was one of omission.  Everything he shows is correct in and of itself, but not sufficient. - I'd upvote you, but I'm equally ignorant of if you're actually right or not. = I will if/once I hear that you solved the OPs problem.

Comment: @Steve https://realpython.com/async-io-python/#the-asyncio-package-and-asyncawait Check this out for info

Answer (score 2):

Make the first line `async def check(reaction, user)`, and call it with `await`.